# Producing matrix with desired determinant

Tags: matrices

Is there a way to make a $4\times4$ matrix composed of Pauli/Identity matrices that has determinant equal to $1$? Something of a general formula? It's interesting to me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "composed of" pauli/identity matrices?

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157319/81360) interesting

Comment: Suppose $\mathbf{P}$ is our $4\times4$ matrix. We can write $\mathbf{P}$ as a $2\times2$ matrix composed of four elements, each of which is a matrix.

Comment: Okay, so in other words you want to have Pauli/identity matrices as *submatrices* of $P$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: To go one step further, the matrix has to have the form $\boldsymbol{P} = \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{A}\quad \overline{\boldsymbol{B}} \\ \boldsymbol{B} \quad \overline{\boldsymbol{A}}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Have you seen [the Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of two matrices before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98810/discussion-between-rodger-kicks-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: If you would like $P$ to be Hermitian, perhaps it makes more sense to have the upper-right entry be $\mathbf B^\dagger (z)$

Answer (score 1):

No, out of the $256$ possible $4\times 4$ block matrices that you can obtain from matrices of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix},\,\,\,
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix},\,\,\,
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-i\\
i&0
\end{pmatrix},\,\,\,
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
there are only $6$ possible determinant values, namely $0,-2,2,-2i,2i$ and $4$. Informally speaking, it is not hard to write a small code to check this.